# Variables not being replaced

Tags: variables, lua, conditional-statements, default-value

I've been experimenting with the Lua Language and it seems as if all the variables are interacting with the conditions except for this one variable. Could take a look at it?

```
function Medicial()
    local varName = "Marcy"
    local varCondition = "Well"
    local varSCondition = "1"  -- 5 = Uncurable, 10 = Well, 15 = Unknown, 20 = Surgery, 25 = Post Surgery, 29 = Bar Surgery
    local varDoctors = "DefultValue"
    local varExStatus = "DefultValue"
    local payment = "You can afford this."
    local total = 400
    if varCondition == "Well" then
        varDoctors = "Dr. Pope, Dr.Roadmiller"
        varStatus = "Yes"
    end
    if varCondition == "Sick" then
        varDoctors = "Dr. Pope, Dr.Rosenhour, Surgeon Rossford"
        varStatus = "No"
    end
    if total > 1000 then
        payment = "You can not afford this."
    elseif total >= 1000 then
        payment = "You can affort this, but you will be broke."
    end
    if varSCondition == 1 then
        varExStatus = "Well"
    end
    if varSCondition == 5 then
        varExStatus = "Uncurable"
    end
    if varSCondition == 15 then
        varExStatus = "Unknown"
    end
    if varSCondition == "20" then
        varExStatus = "Surgery"
    end
    if varSCondition == "25" then
        varExStatus = "Post Surgery"
    end
    if varSCondition == "29" then
        varExStatus = "Bar Surgery"
    end
    print("-=Subject Reports=-\n");
    print("Subject: "..varName.."\nCurrent Condition: "..varCondition.." ("..varExStatus..")\nCurrent Doctors: "..varDoctors.."\nCurrently Recovering? "..varStatus);
    print(">> "..payment);
end
```

It prints:

```
-=Subject Reports=-

Subject: Marcy
Current Condition: Well (DefultValue)
Current Doctors: Dr. Pope, Dr.Roadmiller
Currently Recovering? Yes
You can afford this.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is broken

```
if total > 1000 then
    payment = "You can not afford this."
elseif total >= 1000 then
    payment = "You can affort this, but you will be broke."
end
```

I bet you meant to do this:

```
if total < 1000 then
    payment = "You can not afford this."
elseif total == 1000 then
    payment = "You can affort this, but you will be broke."
end
```

regarding varSCondition: Your varSCondition is a String ("1"), but you're sometimes comparing it to integers (without the "-signs), for example here:

```
if varSCondition == 1 then
```

and sometimes to Strings , for example here:

```
if varSCondition == "20" then
```

All of them should be either a string, or an integer, but dont mix them. try this:

```
local varSCondition = 1  -- 5 = Uncurable, 10 = Well, 15 = Unknown, 20 = Surgery, 25 = Post Surgery, 29 = Bar Surgery
...
if varSCondition == 1 then
    varExStatus = "Well"
end
if varSCondition == 5 then
    varExStatus = "Uncurable"
end
if varSCondition == 15 then
    varExStatus = "Unknown"
end
if varSCondition == 20 then
    varExStatus = "Surgery"
end
if varSCondition == 25 then
    varExStatus = "Post Surgery"
end
if varSCondition == 29 then
    varExStatus = "Bar Surgery"
end
```

Comment: Ok that solved 1 problem **What was I thinking?!**, Now I just need the "DefultValue" solution

Comment: is there another problem?

Comment: Current Condition: Well (DefultValue)

Comment: That makes total sense and I will now becarful of what my hand types, thanks :)

Comment: not a problem. btw, i suggest you inform yourself about arrays in LUA, because they can make code way more beautiful. Your code is an perfect example, you could reduce the number of lines, while making the code easier to edit. You wouldn't even need a single one of the varSCondition if-statements with the proper use of an array ^^